# Gradient only goes to edge of screen - not html (html/css on mobile phone)

Tags: android, html, css

I have been playing with this all day, and I can't quite get it right. There is a light green to dark green gradient background that I have put directly on the html,body { } code. This is a webpage that's being pulled into an app, but I'm also using Chrome to access the page like any other webpage, and the results are the same.

I can't add images just yet (low rep and all), and because this is a banking app on our personal servers, I've been asked not to link anyone. So here's my code (the pieces I believe are relevant).

What it seems to do is first fill to the bottom of the last div in the gradient, and then apply the gradient to the very very background (when I expand the window, the "bottom" gradient changes like's being pulled, but the one behind the divs doesn't change). On my phone (nexus 4 android), the gradient fills the original screen view 100%, but anything below that get's it's own gradient in the same way as above (aka, if I scroll, there's a clear line where the bottom of the screen had been).

I've tried setting html, body with height: 100%, min-height: 100%, or max-height: 100% and none do the trick. Min-height was probably the closest as the other two rendered a plain background color instead of a "second" gradient.

EDIT: Trying to explain better... since I can't do a screenshot, how about a diagram :P

```
--------------------
|  |   (A)       | |   <--- if this is the main page....
|  |            <---------- then (A) is the total area of my content
|  |             | |        to the bottom of my last div.
|  --------------- |        The gradient fills the main page to the bottom
|                  |        of (A) (which spans the full width, poorly represented).
|                  |        But then the entire thing seems to have it's own gradient
|                  |        as well that fills in behind (A) and flows to the bottom,
--------------------        and on a mobile device, the bottom line of (A) is not 
                            the bottom of the last div, but the bottom of the
                            device screen. So when you scroll, that bottom line
                            scrolls up with the rest of the content and there is a
                            second gradient background that fills the rest of the area 
                            like it's supposed to. But the gradient is only applied
                            to one area in the CSS, nowhere else.
```

How do I fix this?

```
html, body
{
    background: #627d4d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #627d4d 0%, #1f3b08 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#627d4d), color-stop(100%,#1f3b08)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #627d4d 0%,#1f3b08 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #627d4d 0%,#1f3b08 100%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #627d4d 0%,#1f3b08 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #627d4d 0%,#1f3b08 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#627d4d', endColorstr='#1f3b08',GradientType=0 );
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
....
</head>
<body>
  <form id="frm" class="container" runat="server">

        <div class="topBar">
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly:

If I do, You have most of your code correct. You want to keep the `margin: 0` as well as the `min-height`. Basically, you want to give your background a fixed position, so as to "keep it in place" even when the document above it scrolls.

Try adding this just below `padding: 0;`...

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```